# Display JSON Data store in JSON in blade (Laravel 8)

Tags: php, laravel

I have produce notifications through email and manage to send the email.

Now I want to change the template provided by Laravel so I create a new customize blade that will be displayed.

I have a problem on transferring the data to the blade view.

Below is my code:

```
public function __construct($offerData)
{
    $this->offerData = $offerData;
}

 public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    /*This is the original code with default template */
    // return (new MailMessage)
    //     ->greeting($this->offerData['name'])
    //     ->line($this->offerData['body'])
    //     ->action($this->offerData['offerText'], $this->offerData['offerUrl'])
    //     ->line($this->offerData['thanks']);

    /*This is the code use to display the customize template*/
    return (new MailMessage)->view(
        'email_notification',
        ['data' => $this->offerData]
    );
```

Below is How I display the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Hi Awak</title>
        </head>

         <body>

              @foreach($data as $data_)
                   <p>{{ $data_ }}</p>
              @endforeach

         </body>

    </html>
```

This is the result:

[image]

I cannot do any specific modification for each data as you can see it only repeat the p tag here.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with the output. You put the p tag in for loop, that's why it's repeating the p tag. If you want to customize how the data is shown in the view, you have to use the html tags and design it manually along with the data.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for help....

I manage to found the solution...

I just store array in array...

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)->view(
        'email_notification',
        ['name' => [$this->offerData['name']],
         'body' => [$this->offerData['body']]
        ]
    );
}
```